# I have created automated deployment scripts for deployment but unable to run them

Tags: bash, unix, deployment, ssh, putty

I have created automated deployment scripts for Dev, Cert, PPE, PROD deployment. Dev scripts are working fine. But I was not able to run the cert one. Can anyone please help. This shell script will take care following tasks:
1. Delete existing 2 files from extracted "book" webapps.
2. Copy new 2 files - Inside extracted “book” webapps from bridge location.

But I am getting issue while running for CERT.

```
#start for each host
for i in "${servers_array[@]}"
do
  ssh_to_remote_host="ssh -l bookweb -i /export/home/apps/bookplus/.ssh/id_dsa ";

#find the hostname and it's application path
case $i in

#CERT3 Viewer Book Server
    b3pclcertview01)
                    app_path=$view_3_app_path;
                    book_config=$view_3_config_path;
                    ;;

#CERT2 Viewer Book Server
    b3bookvm14)
                    app_path=$view_2_app_path;
                    book_config=$view_2_config_path;
                    ;;

#CERT1 Viewer Book Server
    b3bookvm02)
                    app_path=$view_1_app_path;
                    book_config=$view_1_config_path;
                    ;;

#CERT SMS Viewer Book Server
    b3bookvm03)
                    app_path=$sms_1_app_path;
                    book_config=$sms_1_config_path;
                    ;;

#CERT RUMBA Viewer Book Server
    b3bookvm09)
                    app_path=$rumba_1_app_path;
                    book_config=$rumba_1_config_path;
                    ;;

*)   echo "`date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"`  $i is not a valid option exiting"
exit 0;;
esac #end case
if [ "$i" = $deploymentserver ]
then
        ssh_to_remote_host=""; #This is the host from deployment will be done. Therefore it is required to set off ssh command and use normal "cp" command
        i="";
fi
echo "`date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"`  Start deployment at hostname $i ......................"; 

#deleting files - ViewerMain_r49.swf & launchBookViewer.jsp from extracted “book” webapps
rm -rf $app_path/apache-tomcat-6.0.35/webapps/book/jsp/viewer/launchBookViewer.jsp;
rm -rf $app_path/apache-tomcat-6.0.35/webapps/book/flex/ViewerMain_r49.swf;

#verify file is deleted
if [ ! -f "$app_path/apache-tomcat-6.0.35/webapps/book/jsp/viewer/launchBookViewer.jsp" ];
then echo "File 'launchBookViewer.jsp' is deleted";
fi

if [ ! -f "$app_path/apache-tomcat-6.0.35/webapps/book/flex/ViewerMain_r49.swf" ];
then echo "File 'ViewerMain_r49.swf' is deleted";
fi

#start deployment of  file
$ssh_to_remote_host $i cp -rp  $etext_build_location/launchBookViewer.jsp  $app_path/apache-tomcat-6.0.35/webapps/book/jsp/viewer/;
$ssh_to_remote_host $i cp -rp  $etext_build_location/ViewerMain_r4121.swf  $app_path/apache-tomcat-6.0.35/webapps/book/flex/;

if [ "$?" -ne 0 ]
   then
      echo "`date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"`  node ${i} : files could not be deployed";
    exit 0;
else
    echo "`date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"`  files deployed at hostname: $i ......................";  
fi  

done #end deployment
```

Comment: What issue are you getting?

Comment: Please provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure exactly what it is you want, but something is suspicious in this code. You are deleting on the local machine, then copying files on the remote machine. My guess is that you have to use `scp` instead of `ssh` to copy from the remote machine to the local one. Or if you want to do everything on the remote machine, then you should also `ssh` when deleting the files.

In a more general note, run the script with `bash -x` to debug it if you don't know why it fails.